# Mailchimp embedded signup-form with at least one mandatory checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, mailchimp

Mailchimp doesn't support mandatory checkboxes. Here is my code that works for me.`So I take the origin code from Mailchimp Embedded SignUp and added my own validation (basically found on Stackoverflow).

I needed at least one marked checkbox. How to solve this Problem? How I can stop the transmitting if no checkbox is marked?

`````````````````````````````````````````
>Here goes the Button

            <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Zum Infoverteiler anmelden" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" onclick="return valthis()"></div>

        </div>
    </form>

</script>

> Here goes the validation
> look at onclick-event

<script type="text/javascript">
    var isChecked = false;

    function valthis() {
        var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('interest-group');

        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            //alert('var checkBoxes[i].checked=' + checkBoxes[i].checked);

            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                isChecked = true;
                break; //don't need to continue the loop once a checkbox was found
            }
        }

        if (!isChecked) {
            alert('Bitte mindestens einen bla auswählen!');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
````````````````````````````````````````
It's not the complete code. CSS and standard code of Mailchimp is not all included.Good luck!

Searched at Mailchimp and internet but I have not found a solution.

 ``````````````    
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Zum Infoverteiler anmelden" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" onclick="return valthis()"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var isChecked = false;

    function valthis() {
        var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('interest-group');


        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            //alert('var checkBoxes[i].checked=' + checkBoxes[i].checked);

            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                isChecked = true;
                break; //don't need to continue the loop once a checkbox was found
            }
        }

        if (!isChecked) {
            alert('Bitte mindestens einen Studiengang auswählen!');
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
</script>

``````````````````


Sending of form should stop if not at least one checkbos is marked.
`````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: This code above worked for me.

Comment: What your question is unclear. You're stating that the code above worked for you, so then what's your question